# qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed

Tags: qt, openssl, xmlhttprequest, qml

So, I get `qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed` when I try to send XMLHttpRequest.

I use Qt 5.12.2, imsvc2017_64. How can I solve this problem?

```
function requestCall(type){

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest()
    var url = "https://******";
    var params = ""
    params = "operator_id=1&call_id="+call_id;
    console.log("Request (type): "+(type))
    http.open("POST", url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form- urlencoded");
    http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    http.onreadystatechange = function() { }
    http.send(params);
}
```

Comment: Do you have OpenSSL installed?

Answer (score 0):

Adding OpenSSL Support for Android
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-openssl-support.html